# Table with even row heights and vertical alignment

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, tabularx, height

I'm unable to get the following table to have even row heights with vertical alignment

```
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

...

\begin{table}
    \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X X}

        \toprule

        \textbf{Route} & \textbf{Funzione} \\
        
        \midrule

        \lstinline$/device/:id$ & Carica menu di navigazione e toolbar principale
        \\

        \midrule

        \lstinline$/device/:id/dids$ & Mostra la lista dei DID document posseduti dal device \verb+id+
        \\

        \midrule

        \lstinline$/device/:id/keys$ & Mostra la lista delle chiavi pubbliche contenute nei DID document posseduti dal dispositivo \verb+id+
        \\

        \midrule

        \lstinline$/device/:id/credentials$ & Mostra la lista delle credenziali rilasciate al dispositivo \verb+id+
        \\

        \midrule

        \lstinline$/device/:id/credentials/:id/use$ & Consente di accedere al servizio di un Verifier utilizzando la credenziale \verb+id+
        \\

        \midrule

        \lstinline$/device/:id/credentials/:id/revoke$ & Consente di inviare una richiesta di revoca della credenziale \verb+id+
        \\

        \midrule

        \lstinline$/device/:id/issuers$ & Mostra la lista degli Issuer di cui il dispositivo \verb+id+ si fida
        \\

        \midrule

        \lstinline$/device/:id/verifiers$ & Mostra la lista di Verifier conosciuti dal dispositivo \verb+id+
        \\

        \midrule

        \lstinline$/device/:id/status-lists$ & Mostra la lista delle status list
        \\

        \midrule

        \lstinline$/device/:id/settings$ & Espone metodi d'utilità
        \\

    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Lista delle route con relative funzionalità.}
\end{table}
```

By increasing the number in `\arraystretch` the result will always be to have uneven row heights.

Is there a way to have all the row heights to be set with the height of the higher one?

[image]

Comment: So, you want all rows to have the height of 3 lines of text? Please confirm.

Comment: @Mico yes, possibly this behaviour should adapt to the row with the higher number of lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By use of the `tabularray` package this is relative simple to accomplish:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\begin{tblr}{hline{1,Z}=1pt, hline{2}=0.8pt, hline{3-Y}=solid,
             colspec = {@{} Q[m, font=\ttfamily] X[m,j] @{}},
             row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
             row{2-Z} = {ht=3\baselineskip}
             }
Route                   & Funzione    \\
/device/:id             & Carica menu di navigazione e toolbar principale   \\
/device/:id/dids        & Mostra la lista dei DID document posseduti dal device \texttt{id} \\
/device/:id/keys        & Mostra la lista delle chiavi pubbliche contenute nei DID document posseduti dal dispositivo \texttt{id} \\
/device/:id/credentials & Mostra la lista delle credenziali rilasciate al dispositivo \texttt{id}     \\
/device/:id/credentials/:id/use
                        & Consente di accedere al servizio di un Verifier utilizzando la credenziale \texttt{id}  \\
/device/:id/credentials/:id/revoke
                        & Consente di inviare una richiesta di revoca della credenziale \texttt{id}   \\
/device/:id/issuers     & Mostra la lista degli Issuer di cui il dispositivo \texttt{id} si fida  \\
/device/:id/verifiers   & Mostra la lista di Verifier conosciuti dal dispositivo \texttt{id}  \\
/device/:id/status-lists    & Mostra la lista delle status list \\
/device/:id/settings    & Espone metodi d'utilità   \\
\end{tblr}
    \caption{Lista delle route con relative funzionalità.}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What's the effect of using `j` for the column definition `X[m,j]`?

Comment: @AntonioSantoro, formatting of text in cell: `m`: vertical centered, `j` horizontally justified. For detail see package documentation. `j` is available with recent version of `tabularray` package.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with classical packages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}>{\rule[-16pt]{0pt}{40pt}\ttfamily}lX@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{\bfseries Route} & \bfseries Funzione    \\ \hline 
/device/:id             & Carica menu di navigazione e toolbar principale   \\ \hline
/device/:id/dids        & Mostra la lista dei DID document posseduti dal device \texttt{id} \\ \hline
/device/:id/keys        & Mostra la lista delle chiavi pubbliche contenute nei DID document posseduti dal dispositivo \texttt{id} \\ \hline
/device/:id/credentials & Mostra la lista delle credenziali rilasciate al dispositivo \texttt{id}     \\ \hline
/device/:id/credentials/:id/use
                        & Consente di accedere al servizio di un Verifier utilizzando la credenziale \texttt{id}  \\ \hline
/device/:id/credentials/:id/revoke
                        & Consente di inviare una richiesta di revoca della credenziale \texttt{id}   \\ \hline
/device/:id/issuers     & Mostra la lista degli Issuer di cui il dispositivo \texttt{id} si fida  \\ \hline
/device/:id/verifiers   & Mostra la lista di Verifier conosciuti dal dispositivo \texttt{id}  \\ \hline
/device/:id/status-lists& Mostra la lista delle status list \\ \hline
/device/:id/settings    & Espone metodi d'utilità   \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Lista delle route con relative funzionalità.}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 0):

A solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{nicematrix,booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{NiceTabular}{@{}>{\rule[-16pt]{0pt}{40pt}\ttfamily}lX[m]@{}}[hlines={2-11}]
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{\bfseries Route} & \bfseries Funzione    \\
/device/:id             & Carica menu di navigazione e toolbar principale   \\
/device/:id/dids        & Mostra la lista dei DID document posseduti dal device \texttt{id} \\
/device/:id/keys        & Mostra la lista delle chiavi pubbliche contenute nei DID document posseduti dal dispositivo \texttt{id} \\
/device/:id/credentials & Mostra la lista delle credenziali rilasciate al dispositivo \texttt{id}     \\
/device/:id/credentials/:id/use
                        & Consente di accedere al servizio di un Verifier utilizzando la credenziale \texttt{id}  \\
/device/:id/credentials/:id/revoke
                        & Consente di inviare una richiesta di revoca della credenziale \texttt{id}   \\
/device/:id/issuers     & Mostra la lista degli Issuer di cui il dispositivo \texttt{id} si fida  \\
/device/:id/verifiers   & Mostra la lista di Verifier conosciuti dal dispositivo \texttt{id}  \\
/device/:id/status-lists& Mostra la lista delle status list \\
/device/:id/settings    & Espone metodi d'utilità   \\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\caption{Lista delle route con relative funzionalità.}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]